# Variable declaration as a member of a function?

Tags: python-3.x

What type of declaration is the one indicated in this code

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls1 += 1 # <== This
        return func(x)
    helper.calls1 = 0

    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x + 1

print(succ.calls1)

for i in range(10):
    print(succ(i))
    
print(succ.calls1())
```

What's the name of this is the first time i see something like this

Comment: So, one thing to keep in mind, python doesn't really have variable declarations. Everything is an object, and attributes on objects spring into existence when you assign to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are just objects in Python, so the same way you can add new attributes to instances of your own classes (and to the classes themselves) you can add them to your functions:

```
def foo():
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

bar = Bar()

foo.spam = 1
bar.spam = 2

print(foo.spam)  # 1
print(bar.spam)  # 2
```

Generally one wouldn't add new attributes to a function object though, since it can quickly get messy and hard to keep track of.